# Haskell's equivalence of Rust's GAT?

Tags: haskell, rust

What is the Haskell's equivalence of the following Rust code:

```rust
trait Foo {
    type Bar<T>;
    
    fn foo(x: String) -> Self::Bar<String>;
}
```

I tried to write the following:

```hs
class Foo f where
    type Bar f :: * -> *
    foo :: String -> Bar f String
```

But got the error:

```
app/Main.hs:83:5: error:
    • Couldn't match type: Bar f0
                     with: Bar f
      Expected: String -> Bar f String
        Actual: String -> Bar f0 String
      NB: ‘Bar’ is a non-injective type family
      The type variable ‘f0’ is ambiguous
    • In the ambiguity check for ‘foo’
      To defer the ambiguity check to use sites, enable AllowAmbiguousTypes
      When checking the class method:
        foo :: forall f. Foo f => String -> Bar f String
      In the class declaration for ‘Foo’
   |
83 |     foo :: String -> Bar f String
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: That is indeed the equivalent. Go ahead and turn on `AllowAmbiguousTypes` as suggested by the error, and probably `TypeApplications` while you're at it to make it usable. Where in rust you would say `Baz::foo`, in Haskell you then say `foo @Baz`. (Not making this an answer because I don't trust my rust-foo enough to be confident, but if `Baz::foo` didn't make you run screaming "that's not how you use this" then I'm probably right.)

Comment: Another way to write it in Haskell is `class Foo bar where foo :: String -> bar String`

Comment: My Rust-fu is weak, but `TypeApplications` enables `f @SomeType` that should roughly play the same role as in `SomeType::f` for traits or the turbofish `f::<SomeType>` for generic functions. Turning on `TypeApplications` and `AllowAmbiguousTypes` is completely safe: it merely asks Haskell to enable some types that can not be used without the `f @SomeType` syntax (i.e., types that can not be fully inferred later on). Indeed, `TypeApplications` is on by default in recent GHCs.

Comment: @Noughtmare I think that's not quite the same, but I'm not sure. For example, I think it would be possible in the rust version to say that `i64` implements the trait, but `instance Foo Int64` would be ill-kinded with your proposal. (Of course, it may be that for the use-case it's being put to, your proposal is *better*. Dunno. The question would probably be better if it said what the goal was and asked about an idiomatic way to achieve that goal, rather than asking to transliterate from one language to another.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Summarizing the comments:

```
class Foo f where
    type Bar f :: * -> *
    foo :: String -> Bar f String
```

This is correct. Haskell's "ambiguous type" error is warning you about something in a very roundabout way. Specifically, in base Haskell (without any additional extension), the function `foo` can *never* be called. If we pass it a `String`, it will return a `Bar f String`, and `Bar f` is not injective, so even if we know that the result of `foo ""` should be of some particular concrete type, we can never infer `f` from that.

If we had a `data family`, which *is* injective, then we wouldn't get an ambiguous warning. For example,

```
class Foo f where
    data Bar f :: * -> *
    foo :: String -> Bar f String
```

Rust has no equivalent of this, to my knowledge. What this says is that every `instance Foo` defines a new type (not an alias, an actual new type) called `Bar f :: * -> *`. This gives us the very powerful property called *injectivity*: If `Bar f ~ Bar g` then `f ~ g` (where `~` is the [unification operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unification_(computer_science))). The type is no longer ambiguous. If we call `foo` in a context where we know the result must be a `Bar Int String`, then we can conclude with total confidence that the instance we want is `Foo Int`.

Now, because of the way we write function calls in Rust, it's less likely for an associated function (i.e. one without a `self`) to be ambiguous. We would write the equivalent function call in Rust as `Foo::<i32>::foo(...)`, using everybody's favorite turbofish operator, and that tells us which instance we want anyway.

Haskell has a comparable syntax, but it's only available under a [compiler extension](https://downloads.haskell.org/ghc/latest/docs/users_guide/exts/type_applications.html), and unfortunately the ambiguity check is not aware of this extension. To suppress the ambiguity check, we have to enable a [third compiler extension](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/7.8.4/docs/html/users_guide/other-type-extensions.html).

Lastly, there's one more little subtlety. The way you've written your type family implies a little extra that you probably didn't intend.

```
type Bar f :: * -> *
```

This is pretty powerful. It says that `Bar f` must be a well-defined type constructor of one argument. `Bar f` can be `Maybe`, or it can be `[]`, or any other type constructor. But, crucially, it can't depend on its argument in a [nominal](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/-/wikis/roles) way. That is, if we had another type family somewhere (either in a type class or independent), like this

```
type family Baz x where
    Baz Int = [Int]
    Baz String = String
```

Then we cannot write an instance `type Bar f = Baz`, since `Baz` (on its own) is not well-defined. This is a subtlety in Haskell: type aliases must always be fully expanded. That's also true in Rust, but again, since we write our types with a different syntax in Rust, we don't notice it as much. But in Rust, there's no syntax to *declare* a higher-kinded type, since higher-kinded types don't exist.

So the *true* equivalent to the Rust GAT is

```
class Foo f where
    type Bar f x
    foo :: String -> Bar f String
```

Put another way, `type Bar f :: * -> *` says that `Bar f` must be a well-defined value in the Haskell type system whose kind is `* -> *` (and partially-applied type aliases are not valid type-level values). On the other hand, `type Bar f x` only says `Bar f x` must be a well-defined value of kind `*`, which is a much weaker constraint.

So, putting it all together, here's a complete example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, TypeApplications, AllowAmbiguousTypes #-}

-- Random example type family
type family Baz x where
    Baz Int = [Int]
    Baz String = String

-- The type class
class Foo f where
    type Bar f x
    foo :: String -> Bar f String

-- Example instance
instance Foo Int where
    type Bar Int x = Baz x
    foo x = x ++ " It worked!"

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn (foo @Int "Hello from Foo Int!")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bZHRbsIgFIbveYrfeqNxfQETl9VEXROzJZu7WnaBlVoihabQWLfs2bsDVtOLcQHn/Ae@8wMFtyehVNf9xGNsk5fNR7JZYXepxJqXUklhH0KWVJWSGXfSaFISpcw5Kffy2JjG@rrFOP5lLI7xxvXBlBAtLysl4KiI3LMubBBjyb/R4lyIWjDQ8HmqHRb4pOXrrr27WuojydcgtNgVPTdT3FoWZqyNQT4Ahg1LXpPYBiGnDfP5DRg/9sUBd9V7lto6rjPBbkGAe3f/4L3ckr9woXsjr7SYzRAhpWOmPonDKGKs5FJ7F@krJtNrtkDVOHKx1Zj4o0@eGD3Tr9CFanrKvvkomrKu@wM)